# "your parent has blocked access to games and apps that aren't published by microsoft"

Tags: ms-office, ipad

When trying to re-sign-in or add a child's Outlook account to Outlook on an iPad, the web sign-in form appears in a modal web browser dialog, but it displays a message:

> Something went wrong
>
> Your parent has blocked access to games and apps that aren't published by Microsoft...

The message is a Microsoft message displayed within the modal web dialog.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few reports of this on other forums. Adding the child's Outlook account to iOS via Settings > Accounts as a Microsoft Exchange account avoids the web login and thus avoids the issue, though the account is added to iOS and thus their mail will come in to the iOS mail app.

This is not a solution per se, but a workaround. I was unable to find a solution. I am a former Microsoft Outlook engineer and now a web developer. My theory is that this is a bug in Microsoft's sign-in web flow and the user-agent string that the embedded browser login box sends.

You'd think the browser in the embedded modal dialog was Safari, and it must be since iOS can only run Safari, but something's amiss because my daughter can run Safari itself just fine.